# JSCH Win32-OpenSSH SFTP get transfer issues

Tags: java, jsch, openssh

I am using JCraft JSCH (last version) java library to connect to the sshd. What is happening is that I open an sftp channel and do a get, the file is only partially transferred, never full unless is an small file (16.00 KB, or so).

The sftp get code I have is:
`        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream localStream = null;
        try {
            int lastSlash = remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/');
            String remoteDirName = remoteFile.substring(0, lastSlash);

```
        if (! m_session.isConnected()) {
            establishSession(host, port, userName, password);
        }
        m_channel = m_session.openChannel("sftp");
        m_channel.connect(60000);
        ChannelSftp c = (ChannelSftp) m_channel;
        int mode = ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE;

        // Get to the parent of the working directory.
        try {
            lastSlash = remoteDirName.lastIndexOf('/');
            String parentDir = remoteFile.substring(0, lastSlash);
            c.cd(parentDir);
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            throw new RemoteExecutionException(e);
        }

        // Sends the file from the destination.
        // Get to the destination directory
        c.cd(remoteDirName);
        // Then we do the actual get from the remote file to the local directory.
        String tmpLocalFile = localFile;
        localFile = new String (tmpLocalFile.replaceAll("\\\\", "/"));
        SftpATTRS sftpATTRS = c.lstat(remoteFile);
        in = c.get(remoteFile);//, null, mode);
        localStream = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
        int lineCode;
        long remoteSize = sftpATTRS.getSize();
        int localSize = 0;
        while ( (lineCode = in.read()) != -1 ) {
            localStream.write(lineCode);
        }
```

`

In the server side the log is:

```
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: recv - io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: recv - returning 52 bytes from prior completed IO, remaining:0, io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: close_read
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_close fd:11
4784 15:10:36 769 debug1: close - io:00557240, type:2, fd:11, table_index:11
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: fileclose - pio:00557240
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: ReadCB pio:00557240, pending_state:1, error:995, received:0
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: input open -> closed
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: close_write
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_close fd:9
4784 15:10:36 769 debug1: close - io:005573C0, type:2, fd:9, table_index:9
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: fileclose - pio:005573C0
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 769 debug1: session_by_channel: session 2 channel 1
4784 15:10:36 769 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1 child 604
4784 15:10:36 769 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1: has child
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_select fd:4
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_select fd:8
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: w32_select fd:10
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: Total in fds:4
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:1
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: WSARecv - pio: 00556D40
4784 15:10:36 769 debug2: WSARecv - reported IO pending
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 2 childres
4784 15:10:36 769 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 2 childres
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: WSARecvCompletionCB - io:00556D40, pending_state:1, flags:0, error:0, received:52
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: select - returning 1
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 1: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_by_channel: session 2 channel 1
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1 child 604
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1: has child
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: w32_read fd:3
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: recv - io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: recv - returning 52 bytes from prior completed IO, remaining:0, io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: close_read
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: w32_close fd:8
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: close - io:00557340, type:2, fd:8, table_index:8
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: fileclose - pio:00557340
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: ReadCB pio:005577C0, pending_state:1, error:109, received:0
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: ReadCB pio:00557340, pending_state:1, error:995, received:0
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: close_write
4784 15:10:36 770 debug3: w32_close fd:7
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: close - io:005572C0, type:2, fd:7, table_index:7
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: fileclose - pio:005572C0
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 770 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 4528
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0: has child
4784 15:10:36 770 debug1: Sending exit signal to child process [pid = 4528]...
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release console
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: getpwnam: username [Administrator]
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_by_channel: session 2 channel 1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1 child 604
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1: has child
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_select fd:4
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: Total in fds:2
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: WSARecv - pio: 00556D40
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: WSARecv - reported IO pending
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 2 childres
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: zombie'ing child at index 1, 0 zombies of 2
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: process_signals()
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: raise sig:3
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: signal() sig:3, handler:013E1800
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_write fd:5
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: write - io:005571C0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: ReadCB pio:00557140, pending_state:1, error:0, received:1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: WriteCB - pio:005571C0, pending_state:1, error:0, transferred:1 of remaining: 1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: write - reporting 1 bytes written, io:005571C0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: process_queued_signals: WARNING - A signal has interrupted and was processed
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: Unregister child at index 1, 1 zombies of 2
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_by_pid: pid 604
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_exit_message: session 2 channel 1 pid 604
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: request exit-status confirm 0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 4528
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0: has child
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_read fd:13
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: read - io:005577C0 remaining:0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: read - (2) no more data, io:005577C0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: read 0 from efd 13
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: closing read-efd 13
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_close fd:13
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: close - io:005577C0, type:2, fd:13, table_index:13
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: fileclose - pio:005577C0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: ReadCB pio:00557440, pending_state:1, error:109, received:0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: send close
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: is dead
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_by_channel: session 2 channel 1
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 1 child 0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close: session 2 pid 0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: session_unused: session id 2 unused
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: gc: user detached
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: is dead
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: channel 1: free: server-session, nchannels 2
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:

  #0 server-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

  #1 server-session (t4 r18 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)


4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
4784 15:10:36 771 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 4528
4784 15:10:36 771 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0: has child
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 771 debug3: w32_select fd:4
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: Total in fds:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 1 childres
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: zombie'ing child at index 0, 0 zombies of 1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: process_signals()
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: raise sig:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: signal() sig:3, handler:013E1800
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_write fd:5
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: write - io:005571C0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: WriteCB - pio:005571C0, pending_state:1, error:0, transferred:1 of remaining: 1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: write - reporting 1 bytes written, io:005571C0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: process_queued_signals: WARNING - A signal has interrupted and was processed
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: Unregister child at index 0, 1 zombies of 1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_by_pid: pid 4528
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 4528
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: request exit-status confirm 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_read fd:10
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: read - io:00557440 remaining:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: read - (2) no more data, io:00557440
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: read 0 from efd 10
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: closing read-efd 10
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_close fd:10
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: close - io:00557440, type:2, fd:10, table_index:10
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: fileclose - pio:00557440
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: send close
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: is dead
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: session_close: session 0 pid 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: is dead
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:

  #0 server-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)


4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_select fd:4
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_select fd:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: Total in fds:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: on_select - io:00556D40 type:1 rd:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 0 childres
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: WSARecvCompletionCB - io:00556D40, pending_state:1, flags:0, error:0, received:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: select - returning 3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_read fd:4
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: read - io:00557140 remaining:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: read - io:00557140 read: 1 remaining: 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: notify_done: reading
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_read fd:4
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: read - io:00557140 remaining:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: ReadFileEx io:00557140
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: ReadCB pio:00557140, pending_state:1, error:0, received:1
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: read - io:00557140 read: 1 remaining: 0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: notify_done: reading
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_read fd:4
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: read - io:00557140 remaining:0
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: ReadFileEx io:00557140
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: read - IO is pending, io:00557140
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: w32_read fd:3
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: recv - io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: recv - connection closed, io:00556D40
4784 15:10:36 772 Connection closed by 10.73.78.162
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug3: sigprocmask() how:5688184
4784 15:10:36 772 debug2: signal() sig:1, handler:00000000
4784 15:10:36 772 debug1: raise sig:1
5064 15:10:36 774 debug1: zombie'ing child at index 1, 0 zombies of 2
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: process_signals()
5064 15:10:36 774 debug1: raise sig:3
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
5064 15:10:36 774 debug1: Unregister child at index 1, 1 zombies of 2
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: waitpid - pid:-1, options:1
5064 15:10:36 774 debug2: signal() sig:3, handler:013E80F0
5064 15:10:36 774 debug1: process_queued_signals: WARNING - A signal has interrupted and was processed
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: w32_select fd:3
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: Total in fds:1
5064 15:10:36 774 debug2: on_select - io:00286FE0 type:1 rd:1
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: wait() on 0 events and 1 childres
5064 15:10:36 774 debug3: wait() on 1 events and 1 childres
```

Somehow If I go using directly sftp.exe it works fine, but when using a library like the JSCH it does not work fine. I also have tried other get methods from the library.

Does anyone know what is happening, is it the JSCH implementation?

Some more info:
On more data is that if using ChannelSftp.get(String src, String dst) it always retrieve the same size, after several executions it always gets the same. However is not the full file.

```
2016-05-19 11:55:40,884 INFO  [apollo.remotex.spi.agent.manager.UnixRemoteExecutionManager] (EJB default - 1) [Host: 10.73.28.168 Transport: SSH User: Administrator]: SCP: Before getFile: c:\views\src\dsap4\sem\main\local\opt\jboss\bin\dbclassify-mapper\transport\10.73.28.168_10.73.28.168\storage_resources.out -=> storage_resources.out
2016-05-19 11:55:41,014 INFO  [apollo.remotex.spi.agent.net.SCPClient] (EJB default - 1) sftpGet.checkLocalFile.length()=417390
2016-05-19 11:55:41,014 INFO  [apollo.remotex.spi.agent.manager.UnixRemoteExecutionManager] (EJB default - 1) [Host: 10.73.28.168 Transport: SSH User: Administrator]: SCP: After getFile: c:\views\src\dsap4\sem\main\local\opt\jboss\bin\dbclassify-mapper\transport\10.73.28.168_10.73.28.168\storage_resources.out -=> storage_resources.out
```

To help witrh the investigation I have created the following application:
The result log is:

```
    /**
 * Created by jaenf on 19/05/2016.
 */
import apollo.remotex.spi.agent.net.PasswordKeyboardInteractive;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String user = "Administrator";
        String password = "dangerous";
        String host = "10.73.28.168";
        int port=22201;

        String remoteFile="storage_resources.out";

        try
        {
            JSch.setLogger(new JSCHLogger());
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            config.put("cipher.s2c", "aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256");
            config.put("cipher.c2s", "aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256");
            config.put("StrictModes", "no");

            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            // Adding the private keys in the communication.
            session.setIdentityRepository(jsch.getIdentityRepository());
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);

            session.setTimeout(60000); // SESSION_TIMEOUT
            session.setUserInfo(new PasswordKeyboardInteractive(host, password));

            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
            System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel.");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel.connect();
            sftpChannel.cd("/C:/Windows/Temp/UnisphereMapper_IRENSANTOTL1C_10.73.28.168/");
            System.out.println("SFTP Channel created.");
            InputStream out= null;
            out= sftpChannel.get(remoteFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
            sftpChannel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
        catch(JSchException | SftpException | IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();;
            System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

}

```
INFO: Connecting to 10.73.28.168 port 22201
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1p1 Microsoft_Win32_port_with_VS
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO: aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO: aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO: arcfour256 is not available.
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
INFO: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
INFO: kex: client: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added '10.73.28.168' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Authentication succeeded (password).
INFO: Disconnecting from 10.73.28.168 port 22201
INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket Closed
```

Looks like the server sftp is disconnecting. ....

Any idea?

Comment: What happens? Does it throw an exception? What exception? Enable logging and show us the log: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html

Comment: Nothing, close perfectly and noe xception is being launch on the client size. I have JSCH logger activated and I am capturing the exceptions: SftpException, JSchException. Thats the wierd thing. I am suspecting is related to being disconnected from the server.

Comment: If you were disconnected from the server, you would get an exception. Show us the log.

Comment: Does it work if you use the plain `ChannelSftp.get(String src, String dst)`?

Comment: Martin, thanks for the tips, basically I have Logger set on and no exception is being thrown at all. Is just that finished and no error or exception what so ever. That is whats weird. Also I have tried with with the get (src, dst), with the mode imlpentations, etc ... No luck yet.

Comment: I did not ask for the log for the exception, but for download logging. Also, can you download a full file using any GUI SFTP client?

Comment: GUI SFTP client works fine and downloads everything. Only thing I get is after each transfer I get: "2016-05-19 10:08:41,909 ERROR [stderr] (Connect thread 10.73.28.168 session) INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed"  But is an INFO (from JSCH)